# What are the fatigue regulations in the US and Australia for military transport helicopters/rotorcraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, helicopter, casa-regulations, fatigue

For transport category military helicopters, what are the fatigue regulations as specified by the US and Australian regulatory bodies?

I've managed to find that FAA has [14 CFR 29.571](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/29.571) (Fatigue Tolerance Evaluation of Metallic Structure) but this could just be for civil helicopters.

Comment: No. It is a question because I'm finding it difficult to find the above stated information.

Comment: 'Relevant regulations' is very broad.. there's manufacturing, ongoing airworthiness, operations, licensing, noise.. the list goes on and they are often integrated or combined with fixed-wing regulations. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Ben thanks for the clarifications. I'm particularly interested in the regulations related from a structural airworthiness viewpoint.

Comment: @Raptor, perhaps you should edit your question to only ask about Australian CASA regulations. That part of your question is specific and answerable. Your question under Q1) a) seems too broad, since a proper answer would list every applicable regulation from every possible regulatory body worldwide.

Comment: Ok Everyone, I've made the question super specific and look forward to your thoughts. Thank you all for your feedback and helping me to sharpen my question. Best.

Comment: Hello Everyone, I've edited the question considering all your feedback and comments. Could you all please help me to reopen this question? Best.

Comment: Hi Federico, Thank you heaps for voting to reopen my question. @mins also helped me with the editing and sharpening of my question which resulted in the final form as presently posted (Thanks @mins). I look forward to the help from others to reopen. Best.

Comment: Hi Everyone, I will appreciate your feedback and comments on my question. Also, if I need to repost this question, then could you please let me know how to do this. Best. Raptor

Comment: Fatigue is mandatory. It’s the military. That’s why they call your uniform fatigues. It’s present tense.

Comment: DASR is the regulatory authority for Australian military aircraft. The question is unanswerable because they don't make this information available to the public

Answer (score 1):

The US Federal Aviation Administration does not regulate aircraft owned and operated by the military services. I suspect that is the same situation with Australia's CASA.

Parameters for aircraft service life for military aircraft are defined by the manufacturer. The aircraft is designed to meet the requirements specified by the agency requiring the aircraft. This is usually expressed in flight hours, cycles or a combination of that and possibly other parameters.

Comment: "Parameters for aircraft service life for military aircraft are defined by the manufacturer". Incorrect. The regulatory authority is DASA, not CASA in this situation. That info is not made public

Comment: @Craig No. My statement is correct. You only took one sentence and used it out of context. The second sentence addresses your point.

Comment: The manufacturer makes suggestions but the operator and regulatory authority (DASR) define the limits and can actually extend life limits if you mod in strain gauges for instance, or carry out ongoing inspections like NDT. E.g. on Hawk 127 BAe says x hrs, but RAAF decided to implement extra systems (HUMS, NDT, etc.) and now extended life beyond original design life.